# Prove that the set of powers of a set, $\{ A^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ exists by using ZFC axioms (without replacement).

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I need to prove that the set $\{A^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ using the ZFC axioms (without Replacement).

My (rough) plan would be to construct some set containing "more" sets than necessary, then use the comprehension axiom to remove the undesirable sets. Something like: for some $Y$, $\{ X \in Y : \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, X = A^n\}$.

I know how to prove that any one of these sets (e.g., $A^2$), exists, but I have no idea how to prove that the set containing all of these powers exists.

Comment: Replacement, replacement, replacement.

Comment: (Admittedly, that's somewhat of an overkill, but that truly depends on what you mean by $A^n$.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I forgot an important detail: the question specifically says « without Replacement ».

Comment: Then depending on the exact meaning of $A^n$ this just be false.

Comment: Also, if no replacement is allowed, edit the body of the question too!

Comment: @AsafKaragila It defines $A^0 = \{ \emptyset \}$, but doesn't exactly specify what $A^n$ is. I assumed it would be defined by $A^1 = A$, $A^{n+1} = A^n \times A$.

Comment: @ReedOei just use specification on A^\mathbb{N}, no?, A^B usually means the set of all functions from B to A

Comment: @famesyasd Sorry, I don't know what means? Looking at the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), it seems to just be what we referred to as "comprehension" in my class, and I'm not sure which set to use as the superset.

Comment: In that case, you increase the von Neumann rank in each step and thus you have to have some replacement to prove this is a set.

Comment: @famesyasd: This is not helpful for the given definition. Not to mention that you need to quotient that set since functions from $\Bbb N$ are not finite Cartesian products.

Comment: @ReedOei yeah, comprehension = specification, A^B generally means the set of all fucntions from B to A, A^mathbb{N} is the set of all functions from mathbb{N} to A, that is, of all sequences in A, A^n means the set of all functions from n to A, that is of all finite sequences from {0,1,2,..n-1} to A. I'm not sure what I wrote is correct, I'll think that through

Comment: @ReedOei: Given any $x\notin A$, you can identify (any given sensible) $A^n$ with subset of $(A\cup \{x\})^\omega$ consisting of sequences $(a_i)_i$ such that $a_i=x$ iff $i\geq n$. Then you can define your set as a subset of $\mathcal P((A\cup \{x\})^\omega)$.

Comment: @tomasz: But this is not about identifying. It's about a concrete definition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Depends what you really want. Which OP did not clarify. It walks like a duck, it quacks like a duck, I call it a duck.

Comment: @tomasz: When one declare "no replacement", then your argument doesn't work anymore. To prove it's a duck, you must provide genetic analysis. You can't replace the definition of a duck with that one. That is the whole point of replacement!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Given we defined natural numbers as ordinals, perhaps $A^n$ is meant to denote the set of functions from $n$ to $A$. If that is the case, does that resolve any problems?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I know what you mean, but this set has the property "for each $n$, there is a unique element $B\in X$ such that $B=A^n$", and for every $b\in B$, there is some $n$ such that $B=A^n$", where $B=A^n$ means "$B$ is a product of $n$ copies of $A$" (in the category theoretical sense). What it does not satisfy (maybe) is that "it is isomorphic to every set with the same property".

Comment: Yes, that would resolve the problem. That is what I meant by being dependent on the definition. Because iterated Cartesian product, with the standard definition of ordered pairs, won't do.

Comment: @tomasz: People really don't get how much these things break down without replacement. Replacement is literally the reason we are allowed to say "we have this property, and we don't care about the implementation of it". I smell a blog post brewing once I get home.

Comment: @tomasz: http://karagila.org/2019/in-praise-of-replacement/ if I may toot my own horn... :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila That escalated quickly... ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I wouldn't dream of complaining about replacement. I'm rather fond of recursive definitions (well, maybe not all of them; defining $A^1$ as $\{\emptyset\}\times A$ seems rather... unorthodox).

Comment: @tomasz: There's enough people who would define $A^1=A$ and $A^{n+1}=A^n\times A$, the same thing works here. That's not that point. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define $A^n$ as the set of functions from the ordinal $n$ into $A$, then the answer is positive.

Note that a function $n\to A$ is a subset of $n\times A$, and hence also a subset of $\omega\times A$. Thus, every function $n\to A$ is an element of $\mathcal P(\omega\times A)$, so any family of such functions (in particular, every family of *all* such functions for a fixed $n$) is an element of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\omega\times A))$.