# Defining $\{\mathcal{P}^n(\omega) | n\in\omega\}$ using Replacement

Tags: set-theory

The question is actually in the title yet: I’ve heard it during a set theory class, but my problem is that the formula that I’d like to use in order to apply Replacement (of course something whose meaning is $\phi(x,y):$ $x\in\omega\land y=\mathcal{P}(...(\mathcal{P}(\omega))...)$, where obviously dots say “$x$ times”) is not really a formula in the $x$ variable, but just a formula in the $y$ variable depending on $x$. The same problem occurs actually also in defining for example $\omega + \omega$ as the union of the range given by the formula $\phi(x,y):$ $y=\omega + x$, if we think as $+n$ defined by applying the successor $n$ times... Maybe it’s very silly but it quite confuses me how could I get a suitable two variables first order formula.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure other people will know, but what does $\mathcal{P}^n$ mean? Is it the power set operation applied $n$ times?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry I thought it was a quite standard notation

Comment: Do you have transfinite recursion, which is provable from Replacement?

Comment: @Nikio it probably is, I just haven't seen it before.

Comment: @HanulJeon yes, is it helpful?

Comment: @Nikio Yes, as Noah Schweber answered.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138042/prove-that-the-set-of-powers-of-a-set-an-n-in-mathbbn-exists-by and also https://karagila.org/2019/in-praise-of-replacement/

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to how we treat finite sequences of natural numbers in arithmetic (e.g. in Godel's incompleteness theorems): for $n\ge 1$ for simplicity we say that $y=\mathcal{P}^n(x)$ iff there is a sequence $(a_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ such that $a_0=x, a_n=y$, and $a_{i+1}=\mathcal{P}(a_i)$ for $i<n$. So we've replaced a non-first-order definition with a "local" approach.

(Note that this trick is basically how the set-theoretic recursion theorem is proved.)

Answer (score 0):

By induction on $n,$ for each $n\in \omega$ there is a unique $S(n)$ and a unique bijection $f_n:S(n)\to n+1$ such that $f_n(0)=\omega$ and such that $\forall j\in n\, (\,f(j+1)=P(f(j))\,).$ Thus there is a unique $f_n(n),$ which we can write as $P^n(\omega).$